# Tensorflow-gpu 2.5.0 from conda doesn't recognise GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, conda, tensorflow2.0

I made a new conda environment and installed tensorflow-gpu from conda (the latest version is 2.5.0). Then, I tested to see if the environment recognizes my GPU, and it does not. It returns

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 1364016363571256103
]
```

when running the list locality function on tensorflow. What am I missing?

I installed cuDNN and cudatoolkit as dependencies from the conda installation when installing tensorflow-gpu.

```
cudnn==8.2.1.32
cudatoolkit==11.3.1
```

The list of commands I ran were:

```
conda create --name ML4
conda activate ML4
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.5
```

and then in python

```py
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

which yielded the above statement which only recognizes my CPU and not my GPU.

Comment: What `cuda` and `cudnn` version do you have ?

Comment: I added some information in my post if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF 2.5 pre built binaries are compatible with CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1
See tested build configuration chart https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu.
Therefore you have to roll back to cuda 11.2
Thanks!